# _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse) C++ FILE

Tags: c++

I know there are several posts on this error but they are of specific cases.
I'm making a file split/joiner, which has the following requirement:
-User must enter file name/input path and output folder.
I wrote the split function with the basic part of splitting original file into N part (which user must enters) and everything was fine.
I then made some modifications to the function to meet the "output folder" requirement and then when I ran the program, that error appeared (was successfully built though).
Can someone explain/clarify what do I do wrong in my code? I am still a beginner at handling file/memory leaks so all helps/criticism are appreciated.

```
char *GetFileName(char *path)
{
    char *filename = strrchr(path, '\\');
    if (filename == NULL)
        filename = path;
    else
        filename++;
    return filename;
}

void split_F(const char* file_name, const char* output_folder, int number_of_part)
{
    FILE *fp_read = fopen(file_name, "rb");

    //calculate file size
    int file_size;
    fseek(fp_read, 0L, SEEK_END);
    file_size = ftell(fp_read);
    rewind(fp_read); //reset file pointer

    //calculate number of parts
    long size_of_part;
    size_of_part = (int)ceil((double)file_size / number_of_part);
    cout << "Total files after split: " << number_of_part << endl
        << "...Processing..." << endl;


    //extract file name
    char *first_part = new char[255];
    char *temp = new char[255];
    strcpy(temp, file_name);
    first_part = GetFileName(temp);
    cout << endl << "File name is: " << first_part;


    //main process
    char* name = new char[255];
    strcpy(name, output_folder);
    int bytesRemaining = file_size;

    //create buffer
    char *buffer = new char[size_of_part];

    for (int count = 1; count <= number_of_part; count++)
    {

        sprintf(name, "%s.part_%03d", first_part, count);  //attach file name to output directory

        FILE *fp_write = fopen(name, "wb");

        long partSize;
        if (bytesRemaining > size_of_part)
        {
            partSize = size_of_part;
        }
        else
        {
            partSize = bytesRemaining;
        }

        fread(buffer, partSize, 1, fp_read);
        fwrite(buffer, partSize, 1, fp_write);

        cout << "> File: " << name << " done babe!" << endl;

        fclose(fp_write);
    }
    fclose(fp_read);

    delete[] buffer;
    delete[] name;
    delete[] temp;
    delete[] first_part;
}
```

Comment: `I know there are several posts on this error but they are of specific case`  Your case is no different.  You are mismanaging pointers, overrunning a buffer and/or corrupting the heap.  And why are you not using `std::string` instead of `new char[]`?

Comment: I know it's weird but my teacher doesn't allow me to use std::string until taught. He said that by using old-school C array I will get the idea of using pointer.

Comment: The other thing is that your OS (probably Windows) has an API already built that extracts parts of the file name (part of shlwapi.lib).  There is no need to write your own code to do this.

Comment: Your "teacher" needs a teacher.  Learning about pointers does not mean you use `new[]` and `delete[]`.  Also It is simple to call `new[]` and `delete[]`, Big deal -- that isn't teaching you really anything.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie please give me more details :D I have just ventured into C++ for about 5 months, I don't have much experience.

Comment: The code you have has a *lot* of issues.  More than likely, your teacher only knows 'C', and is just falling back on what they really know.

Comment: I'm in Viet Nam, education in here is pretty much obsolete :D

Comment: Can you tell us how you're calling this `split_F` function?  What are the actual parameter values?

Comment: The user has to enter file name (ex: video.MP4 or E:\demo\video.MP4), output folder name and number of parts to split @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: No I mean give me the actual parameters used that caused the exception.

Comment: file name was: E:\demo\abs.MP4
. Output folder: E:\output
. Num of parts: 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your code has a *lot* of issues, all due to using C-style coding instead of using C++.  Instead, if you used `std::string` and C++ streams, a lot of these issues will resolve themselves.

First issue is that you never checked if the file existed:

```
FILE *fp_read = fopen(file_name, "rb");
```

If `fp_read` is NULL, you never checked for it, and your code goes on as if nothing is wrong.  This is incorrect.

Then in your code you do this:

```
  FILE *fp_write = fopen(name, "wb");
```

Again, you go on without checking if `fp_write` is ok, when it could be NULL.

---

But let's assume that `fp_read` and `fp_write` are not NULL

```
//extract file name
char *first_part = new char[255];
char *temp = new char[255];
strcpy(temp, file_name);
```

There are 2 potential problems with the above.

The first problem is that you do no check to ensure that `file_name` is less than 255 characters.  If `file_name` is larger than expected, you have a memory overwrite at the call to `strcpy`.  Use `strncpy` or `memcpy` where you state the number characters to copy over.

The second issue is more subtle, and that is you called `new[]` twice.  What if the second call to `new[]` throws an exception?  How are you going to deallocate the first call to `new[]`?  You can't.  In addition, your input file will still be opened due to the exception being thrown.

This is why `std::string` and `ifstream` `ofstream` should be used in these cases.  These types automatically release any resources allocated if the function returns for any reason whatsoever.  Using `C` style strings and I/O leaves you vulnerable to leaks.

The same issue here:

```
//main process
char* name = new char[255];
strcpy(name, output_folder);
int bytesRemaining = file_size;

//create buffer
char *buffer = new char[size_of_part];
```

All of these calls to `new[]` can potentially `throw`, thus leaving this function, and leaving you with memory leaks and open file handles.

---

The other issue is that you need to ensure that your `buffer` does not get overrun.  This code:

```
    long partSize;
    if (bytesRemaining > size_of_part)
    {
        partSize = size_of_part;
    }
    else
    {
        partSize = bytesRemaining;
    }
```

can be shortened to this:

```
partSize = std::min(bytesRemaining, size_of_part);
```

This makes it clear what your intentions are.

---

Another issue is that your `bytesRemaining` never gets updated during the loop where you're writing your output.  You should have

`bytesRemaining -= partSize;`

within the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Paul McKenzie covered most of this, but there are some other problems with your string handling. The best solution is to use C++ features like he said (`std::string`, `std::ifstream`, [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream), [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), etc.), but if you want to do the C way, there are some improvements you can make.

```
//extract file name
char *first_part = new char[255];
char *temp = new char[255];
strcpy(temp, file_name);
first_part = GetFileName(temp);
cout << endl << "File name is: " << first_part;
```

First, you allocate a new 255-byte string for `first_part`, and then 3 lines later you throw it away and replace it with the result of `GetFileName(temp)`. `temp` itself is a copy of `file_name` but it's not clear why since you never change either of them. Maybe you got a warning passing `file_name` to `GetFileName()`? Try changing the function signature to add `const`:

```
const char *GetFileName(const char *path)
```

Then change the block of code above into:

```
//extract file name
first_part = GetFileName(temp);
cout << endl << "File name is: " << first_part;
```

Now you have 2 fewer heap allocations to deal with.

Now if you look at this code:

```
char* name = new char[255];
strcpy(name, output_folder);
/* ... */
for (int count = 1; count <= number_of_part; count++)
{
    sprintf(name, "%s.part_%03d", first_part, count);
```

There are two problems here. The first is that `name` has a constant size and it isn't very big, so there's no need to allocate it on the heap with `new`. Just declare it as `char name[255];` and the memory will be handled for you.

The second problem is that you copy `output_folder` into `name`, and then a few lines later you overwrite it. So, just remove that `strcpy`.

The third problem is that `first_part` could be 255 bytes long, and `name` is only 255 bytes long, so your `sprintf` could overflow. I would fix this by making `name` at least 15 bytes longer, and using [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) just in case.

Result:

```
char name[300];
/* ... */
for (int count = 1; count <= number_of_part; count++)
{
    snprintf(name, sizeof(name), "%s.part_%03d", first_part, count);
```

Comment: _Please_ avoid using or recommending `std::auto_ptr`. Not just because it's deprecated and will soon go away, but because it's *broken* (see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1856.html#20.4.5%20-%20Class%20template%20auto_ptr). But don't worry: there are much better tools  available for your use: `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @NikBougalis Ok, removed that. I don't actually use C++ much so I tend to fall behind on these things :\